# MYSQLi num_rows always returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am still new in the PHP and MySQL. I just started to learn MySQLi before few days and I met this problem.
This page is named login.php. The problem is that the query return 0 num rows.
When I run the query in phpmyadmin it show this message and 1 row.

> Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0010 sec)

Image:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'config.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$salt = 'qwerty';
$pass_prepare = md5($salt).sha1($password);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
if (isset($username) && isset($pass_prepare)) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_con, "SELECT user_id, username, password, rank, last_activity FROM imes_users WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $pass_prepare);
    mysqli_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $username1, $password1, $rank, $last_activity);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    echo mysqli_num_rows($stmt);
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Could you help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$count = $sql->num_rows; // $count contains now your value
```

Comment: He's using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are using prepared statements, so the syntax is slightly different.  You want to use `mysqli_stmt_num_rows` instead of `mysqli_num_rows`.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_con, "SELECT user_id, username, password, rank, last_activity FROM imes_users WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $pass_prepare);
mysqli_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $username1, $password1, $rank, $last_activity);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
echo mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but it returned 0 again.

Here is var_dumb of $stmt:

object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) {

["affected_rows"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["param_count"]=>
  int(2)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(5)
  ["errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error_list"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
}